# I would like to know the best way to implement the following

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, enumerable

I have a collection of User data, and I want to get the first_name all those users. We can simply use

```
user_list.map(&:first_name)
```

similarly for middle and last name, I need to do the same

```
user_list.map(&:middle_name)
user_list.map(&:last_name)
```

as we can see here I have to loop over the same data 3 times to get collection of first, middle and last name. Can anyone suggest me a way I can do that in a single loop.

so the output will be like.

```
{first_name: ["tom", "harry", "ronald"], middle_name: ["marvello", "james", "bilius"], last_name: ["riddle", "potter", "weasley"] }
```

PS, its not an active record call to use pluck. Its a collection of record on which i need to run this, not a Active record call.

Comment: When asking a question, try to come up with a title that indicates what you're asking. "I would like to know the best way to implement the following" tells us nothing. Perhaps "How to collect object attributes into arrays" would tell searchers something.

Comment: @theTinMan Will keep in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An obvious solution is an [`each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-each) loop:

```
names = {first_name: [], middle_name: [], last_name: []}    
user_list.each do |user|
  names[:first_name] << user.first_name
  names[:middle_name] << user.middle_name
  names[:last_name] << user.last_name
end
```

Or using [`each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
user_list.each_with_object(first_name: [], middle_name: [], last_name: []) do |user, names|
  names[:first_name] << user.first_name
  names[:middle_name] << user.middle_name
  names[:last_name] << user.last_name
end
```

Comment: I have currently implemented it with each loop only, but each_with_object looks good, din knew about that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
user_attributes = ['first_name','middle_name','last_name']
# A hash to hold final result
hsh = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
user_attributes.each do |attr|
  hsh[attr] = user_list.collect {|i| i.send(attr)}
end 
#Result
#$hsh
#{first_name: [...],middle_name: [...],last_name: [...]}
```

## Update

As the above answer has 3 iterations, you can do it with single via `flat_map`

```
user_attributes = [:first_name,:middle_name,:last_name]
collection = user_list.flat_map { |user| [{first_name: user.first_name,middle_name: user.middle_name,last_name: user.last_name}] }


# A hash to hold final result, as u need then as collection. aggregating the independent keys
hsh = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
user_attributes.each {|attr| hsh[attr] = collection.collect {|i| i[attr] }
```

Comment: That is still 3 iterations.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, thanks for pointing, tried another one with a flat map

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [pluck](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck)

```
user_list.pluck(:first_name, :middle_name, :last_name)
```

It will work on ActiveRecord results.

Comment: its not a active record call, sorry I didn't mention it. I already have a collection on which I need to run this.